# " for all x in E , we have p(x) "

Tags: logic

Let E be an empty set .
why the assertion "$(\forall x \in E) , p(x)$ " is true ??

Comment: It's a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: What would a counterexample look like?

Comment: Because there isn't any $x \in E$ where $p(x)$ is false

Comment: Use the principle of vacuous truth: $A\implies (\neg A \implies B)$ (a tautology). In your example, you have $A~\equiv~ x\notin E~$ and $~B~\equiv ~ p(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question should be posted on the Stock Exchange.

However, the empty set is the set that does not contain any element, so the part $x \in E$ is already false, therefore both $F \to F$, and $F \to T$ are True.

Comment: ok thanks sir .